# Position, Rotation and Scale blocked when I imported model with animation, any help?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, import, .fbx

I recently made a polar bear model with an animation that I wanted to import into another Blender file, but when I imported it over using FBX (the animation stayed which was good) it's scale etc. cannot be changed and always returns back to the original imported state.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can use *File -> Append* to add objects (or collections) from one blend file to another blend file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue once, but It turns out that my position rotation and scale parameters in the Item Transform property panel was locked. U can try unlocking it.

But since this is an animation, I would advice checking your scale in each keyframe to make sure that its not changing.